# submitting forms in large quantities

Tags: php, javascript, forms, macros, submit

i have a website where I have a textbox and in that textbox I enter an email and click submit and that email is processed. Problem is I have about 1243 emails I must enter into the submit box and click submit each time and its been getting tedious but even with a macro this process is really slow...So I was wondering is there a JS or PHP script I could write in which I enter the list of emails I want to submit and that PHP or JS list will individually add each email to the textbox and click submit and do that for all 1243 emails?

So basically how it is right now, I open a browser, go to my site www.site.com and at that site I am told to put in an email in textbox, click submit, go back, enter the next email into textbox, click submit, then go back enter another email, click submit, then go back...

each submit leads me to a redirect so that is which I click back...is there a faster way of doing this with JS or PHP?

Comment: is it your own site you are submitting emails to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit a page your browser will just perform a GET or POST request to the page listed under the 'action' attribute of the form (unless there is JavaScript going on).

You can just write a PHP script that will successively make GET or POST requests to the action URL with the email as data.

If there is JavaScript behind the form and an ajax call is fired, figure out what the service signature looks like and perform those requests instead.

This may be a lot harder if the site requires some form of authentication (like cookies) but with PHP's cURL library you can go a long way. Just Google for examples on how to use it.